# Number of ways to express a number as the sum of different integers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, summation

Given a number $n$, then  $P_k(n)$ is the number of ways to express $n$ as the sum of $k$ integers. For example $P_2(6)=7$

$0+6=6$

$1+5=6$

$2+4=6$

$3+3=6$

$4+2=6$

$5+1=6$

$6+0=6$

Now I worked out that $P_2(n)=n+1$ and $P_3(n)$ may be $P_3(n)=\sum^n _{k=0} P_2(n-k)$ but the question is:

**Given $k$ and $n$ is there a formula to always find $P_k(n)$?**

Comment: $3+3=6$ does not look like the sum of *different* integers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is such a formula (assuming $k$ and $n$ are natural numbers).

In order to find it, I suggest you the following:

> Let $k, n\in \Bbb N$. Suppose you have $n$ balls (representing the number $n$), what you want is the number of ways to place this $n$ balls on $k$ boxes (each box will represent the number being added), this can be encoded with a list of the balls, using vertical lines to separate the boxes.
>
> For example, the partition $6=3+2+1$ can be encoded as
>
> $$\bigcirc \bigcirc \bigcirc \mid \bigcirc \bigcirc \mid \bigcirc$$
>
> Each partition correspond to a sequence of $n$ balls and $k-1$ separators, and each such a sequence correspond to a partition, so it suffices to count those sequences.

---

Those sequences are easy to count:

> Those sequences consist of $n+k-1$ characters ($n$ balls and $k-1$ separators), just choose $k-1$ positions for the separators among all the $n+k-1$ available: $\binom {n+k-1}{k-1}$

Comment: how do you do this tipe of answer? I mean with this style of  background.

Comment: Just use > at the beginning of the paragraph.

Comment: how can I hide text like you?

Comment: @LuisFelipeVillavicencioLopez Use >! (suggestion: click the "edit" button below an answer to see its latex typesetting).

Comment: oh, really sorry and thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> If you have $a+b+c=n$ with  $a,b,c,n$ positive integers, then the number of ways is  $\left( \begin{matrix} n+2 \\ 2 \end{matrix} \right)$. wait and i'll make some latex draw to explain this:
>
> [image]

Comment: Then you have to count the number of ways to put $2$ plus sign in $n+2$ squares, did you get it?

Answer (score 1):

The general formula is given by $$P_{k}(n) = \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$$

For similiar reasons as in above Luis Felipe VillavicencioLopez's picture.

Comment: not similar reasons, for the same reason haha ;)