# How to find the right way to solve a given problem?

Tags: probability

> We distribute  10 **indistinguishable** balls to 5 girls.
>
> All the distributions have **equal probability**
>
> Let X be the number of girls who get **at least** 1 ball

I need to find $Pr(X=3)$ and $E[X]$

But there are a few things I did not understand.

1. Why do I need the info that all the distributions have equal probability? What would have happen without it?
2. I can't find the right module to use here, I thought it's related to binomial distribution but seems like I can't apply it properly, I probably don't understand it enough -> how & when to use it and if here is the right case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The fact that all distributions have the same probability means that the probability of any one event occurring is $1/\text{Total number of distributions}$.  In other cases, this formula would be incorrect.  Basically, the statement is saying what process is used to distribute the balls.

Comment: @MichaelBurr so each girl has $0.5$ chance to get a ball and $1-(0.5)^{10}=0.999$ to get at least 1 ball, but the fact that a given girl got at least 1 ball will affect my other calculations so I don't know how to find $X=3$

Comment: The answer to "What would have happened without it?" is: The question wouldn't have been well-defined, since there's no meaning to talking about probabilities and expectation values without assuming some probability distribution. Sometimes problems don't specify one because the author (often wrongly) believes that a certain distribution is clearly implied. In the present case, the most natural assumption if no distribution had been specified might have been that each ball is given to any one of the girls with equal probability $\frac15$.

Comment: In that case, the indistinguishable distributions that are taken as equiprobable here would *not* have been equiprobable. In this sense, this specification makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. What is the total number of distributions?  Let $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$, and $x_5$ be the number of balls that each girl receives (I assume that I can tell the girls apart).  We know that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=10$ and they are all nonnegative integers.  Therefore, the number of values for $x_1,\cdots,x_5$ is the number of sums of $5$ nonnegative integers equalling $10$.  This is a standard problem (related to the "stars and bars" problem (not the flag)), one solutions can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275803/number-of-ways-to-express-a-number-as-the-sum-of-different-integers?rq=1).  In this case, $n=10$ and $k=5$, and the standard count is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{14}{4}=1001$.
2. To compute $Pr(X=3)$, first consider what $X=3$ means; there are exactly three girls who have balls and two which do not.  In the sum above, exactly two of $x_1,\cdots,x_5$ are zero and exactly three are nonzero.  The first question is which three are nonzero?  There are $\binom{5}{3}=10$ ways to select these three girls.
3. Now, you've selected which three girls will receive at least one ball.  Assume that these three are $(i,j,k)$.  Therefore $x_i$, $x_j$, and $x_k$ are all positive and $x_i+x_j+x_k=10$.  This is another ["stars and bars" problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), but the number of ways that this can occur is $\binom{10-1}{3-1}=\binom{9}{2}=36$.

Therefore, the number of ways to have *exactly* three girls receive *at least* one ball is $10\cdot 36=360$.  Since there were $1,001$ ways to distribute the balls, the probability $Pr(X=3)=\frac{360}{1001}$.  To compute the expectation, generalize the ideas in this approach.

Comment: Thanks does each time I get a problem like this I need to calculate it by hand? since I know there are some modules that apply to certain problems where you know the formula of P(X) and the Var and E[X]. Also for the expectation do I need to find X=1,2,4,5 now and work by definition? or there is a faster way than this?

Comment: Usually a problem is not a "standard type" as you describe, but it can be *broken down* into standard problems (like what is done above).  So, I guess the answer to your first question is yes and no?  Yes, you will need to compute the *probabilities* $Pr(X=i)$ for $i=1,2,4,5$ to compute the expectation.  If you understand the case where $Pr(X=3)$, then you can use the same ideas and construction to make quick work of the other cases.

Comment: I have a question: If we let Y to be the number of girls who got 0 balls can I say that the Var(Y) = Var(X)? because only 1 girl that gets at least 1 ball is the same case as exactly 4 girls that do not get any so I just felt like I could calculate Var(X) instead of now doing all over again with Y, is it right?

Comment: If you've already computed everything for $X$, then you can easily compute $Y$ because $Y=5-X$, so the probabilities are the same, but the values of the random variables are different.

Comment: I've found that $Var(X) = 0.705$ and $E[X]=3.571$ so I said that $Var(Y)=0.705$ since they are the same by formula but it seems like it is wrong the only closest answer is 0.71 and I don't understand why I'm off by 0.005 or its ok to be wrong in such a small margin?

Comment: Do they ask for the answer to be rounded?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.- 10 balls to five girls, consider:

10-0-0-0-0

9-1-0-0-0

8-2-0-0-0

8-1-1-0-0

...
...