# Number of ways to express an integer N as sum of 4 integers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

In reference to the question mentioned here :
[Number of ways to express a number as the sum of different integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1275803/343517),

what would be the number of ways to express the number if there is an additional constraint on the ordering of the k integers? For example - if a,b,c,d are k positive integers which express the number and the required ordering constraint is:

a <= b <= c <= d.

There is also a programming solution to this example here: [Number of ways to express an integer N as sum of 4 integers](http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/5481/number-of-ways-to-express-an-integer-n-as-sum-of-4-integers)
which I can't seem to understand.

There is a same question here too [In how many ways I can write a number N as sum of 4 numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1341902/343517)
However, the method used in the above mentioned programming solution looks simple. It would be of great help if the method could be explained easily.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get a solution with complexity $\mathcal O (1)$

there are $5$ types of solutions:

- All numbers are equal
- three equal numbers and one distinct
- two and two
- one pair and the other two distinct
- all different

let $A,B,C,D,E$ be the number of solutions of each type.

Clearly $A=1$ if $4|N$ and $0$ otherwise.

We have $B=\lfloor (N-1)/3 \rfloor-A$

we have $C=0$ if $C$ is odd and $C=(N/2-1-A)/2$ otherwise.

We have $D=[(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2i<N}N-2i-1)-C]/2-B$.

Finally, using stars and bars we get $E=\frac{\binom{N-1}{3}-A-4B-6C-12D}{4!}$.

And clearly you want $A+B+C+D+E$

Comment: Please verify. I took the N value as 15 for example. [Here is a sample program for finding out the values of a, b, c and d and its outputs. ](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/O3XIXm)

Comment: I calculated all the different types of solutions. A = 0, B = 4, C = 0, D = 17, E = 6. But as you described B as ⌊N/3⌋−A, it's value is 5. And I am not clear about the small 'n'. Is it the same as N? How to calculate the value of D with 'n'? Is it 4?

Comment: yeah, $B$ should be $\lfloor (N-1) /2$, I forgot to take into account the fourth number, which must be positive. It should be ok now.

Comment: yes, the small $n$ should be big. Fixed

Comment: Ok. How do I get D? Small n

Comment: Alright, great. Thanks! Checking again..

Comment: Since C = 0, D = (15-3)+(15-5)+(15-7)+(15-9)+(15-11)+(15-13) = 12+10+8+6+4+2 = 42. But as I said, I could calculate the D value for N=15 as 17, which is lot less than 42.

Comment: Ok, let me revise it properly.

Comment: Should be ok now. Give it a run!

Comment: Only E value remains unsatisfied. E should be 6, which is coming out to be 24.83333. (816 - 0 - 16 - 0 - 204)/24 = 596/24 = 24.83333

Comment: oh, of course! I need to use stars and bars so that all of them are positive. Should be ok now

Comment: Yes, everything seems correct. Thanks a lot. Sorry for the trouble, but I have never heard of using stars and bars. What is it's work?